# Spark reading data from IBM Informix database "Not enough tokens are specified in the string representation of a date value"

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, informix

I tried to connect to a Informix database in spark using the following syntax.

```
jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:informix-sqli://192.168.x.xx:xxxx/INFORMIXSERVER=online").option("dbtable", "informix.detail").option("user", "user").option("password", "xxxxxx").option('driver','com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver').load()
```

Conncection was successful and I could see the schema of the dataframe.

```
jdbcDF.printSchema() 

   root
 |-- mobile_no: string (nullable = false)
 |-- subscriber_code: string (nullable = false)
 |-- connected_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- disconnected_on: date (nullable = true)
 |-- att0: string (nullable = true)
```

But when retrieve the data from the dataframe,

```
jdbcDF.show()
```

I get the following error.

> Not enough tokens are specified in the string representation of a
>   date value. "disconnected_on"

I found a same problem in the internet,
[IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_424.htm)
 and it says I need to change  the database column in the Informix database but, in my case that  is not possible.

Is their any way I can cast the 'disconnected_on' field in to string in the dataframe before load from informix table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to cast a column, you can use `cast()`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.cast

```
>>> df.select(df.age.cast("string").alias('ages')).collect()
[Row(ages=u'2'), Row(ages=u'5')]
```

You can drop the old column using `drop()`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

**drop(*cols)**

```
Returns a new DataFrame that drops the specified column. This is a no-op if schema doesn’t contain the given column name(s).
Parameters: cols – a string name of the column to drop, or a Column to drop, or a list of string name of the columns to drop.

>>> df.drop('age').collect()
[Row(name=u'Alice'), Row(name=u'Bob')]

>>> df.drop(df.age).collect()
[Row(name=u'Alice'), Row(name=u'Bob')]
```

Combining those two functions, you can add a new column `disconnected_on_str`, which is `disconnected_on` `cast` to be `string`, and `drop` the old column `disconnected_on` :

```
jdbcDF_cast = jdbcDF.withColumn("disconnected_on_str", jdbcDF["disconnected_on"].cast("string")).drop("disconnected_on")
```